# if $g|ab$ , $g|cd$, $g|ac+bd$, show $g|ac$ and $g|bd$.

Tags: number-theory

Struggling to solve this problem.  Professor suggest we look at $p^n$ as one of the prime factorizations of $g$ (note $p^{n+1}$ doesn't divide $g$) and likewise the number of $p$'s in $a, b, c,$ and $d$ respectively are exactly $r, s, t, u$. His hint is to look at the inequalities among $n, r, s, t, u$ that follow from the divisibility assertions.

Comment: Can you write down some of those inequalities? The first two are easy.

Comment: $n <= r+s$ and $n <= t+u$ ?

Comment: while working with the problem I tried to go in the direction of saying $r+s$ was equal to $n$ and so was $t+u$ so the sum of $r, s, t, v$ must be 2n but am unsure where to go from there.

Comment: Yes. For the third one: suppose $p^i$ is the highest power of $p$ that divides $x$, and $p^j$ is the highest power of $p$ that divides $y$. Then if $i \ne j$, the highest power of $p$ that divides $x+y$ is $\min(i,j)$, which gives you your result immediately. If $i = j$ (or in this case, if $r+t=s+u$), you need a separate argument., which is not difficult.

Comment: so if if the highest power of $p$ that divides $x+y$ is $min(i, j)$ I'm assuming that is $n$ but how does that show $g|ac$ or $g|bd$

Comment: Alternatively, $ac/g$ is a root of the monic polynomial $X^2 - \dfrac{ac+bd}{g}X + \dfrac{ab}{g}\cdot\dfrac{cd}{g}$, and thus an algebraic integer. But any algebraic integer which is rational must be an integer.

Comment: Adding your two inequalities gives $2n \le r+s+t+u$. And if $r+t=s+u$, this gives $2n \le 2(r+t)$, so $n \le r+t$; similarly $n \le s+u$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the highest power of $p$ that divides $g$ is $k_g$, i.e., $p^{k_g}\mid g$ and $p^{k_g+1}\nmid g$.  Continuing, let $k_a$ be the highest power of $p$ that divides $a$, $k_b$ the highest power of $p$ that divides $b$, $k_c$ the highest power of $p$ that divides $c$ and $k_d$ the highest power of $p$ that divides $d$.

Since $g\mid ab$, it follows that $k_g\leq k_a+k_b$.  Similarly, since $g\mid cd$, $k_g\leq k_c+k_d$.  We consider a few cases:

Suppose that $p^{k_g}\mid ac$.  Then, since $g\mid ac+bd$, it follows that $p^{k_g}\mid ac+bd$ so $p^{k_g}\mid bd$.  A similar case holds if $p^{k_g}\mid bd$.

On the other hand, if $p^{k_g}\nmid ac$ and $p^{k_g}\nmid bd$.  Then, $k_g>k_a+k_c$ and $k_g>k_b+k_d$.  Combining these inequalities, $2k_g>k_a+k_b+k_c+k_d$.  On the other hand, from the original inequalities, $2k_g\leq k_a+k_b+k_c+k_d$, which is a contradiction, so this case is impossible.

Therefore, $p^{k_g}\mid ac$ and $p^{k_g}\mid bd$.  Since the choice of $p$ is arbitrary, every prime divisor of $g$ has this property.  Hence $g\mid ac$ and $g\mid bd$.